# JS Promise.all in recursion

Tags: javascript

I need some help with JS promises.

There is a data on a server:

{ id: 1,
name: 'org_1',
parent_id: 0
},
{ id: 2,
name: 'org_2',
parent_id: 0
},
{ id: 3,
name: 'dep_1',
parent_id: 1
},
{ id: 4,
name: 'dep_2',
parent_id: 1
},
{ id: 5,
name: 'dep_1',
parent_id: 2
}
...

And a simple peace of code getting data:

```
const fetchData = async (params) => {
  const url = new URL(REMOTE_APP_HOST);
  url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: "Basic " + API_ACCOUNT,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }),
  });
  return await response.json();
};

const findOrgs = async (parent_id) => {
  const params = {
    parent_id: parent_id,
  };

  try {
    return await fetchData(params);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("findOrgs, fetch error: ", err);
  }
};

const orgsData = async (parent_id) => {
  const data = []
 
  const organizations = await findOrgs(parent_id);

  for (const organization of organizations) {
    const organizationData = {
      name: organization.name,
      type: "organization",
      children: [],
    };

    organizationData.children = await orgsData(
      organization.id
    );

    data.push(organizationData);
  }

  return data
};

const orgsList = async () => {
  return await orgsData(0);
};
```

How to implement a parallel version of the 'orgsData' function using Promise.all?

My effort:

```
const organizationData = async (organization) => {
  const data = [];

  const orgData = {
    name: organization.name,
    type: "organization",
    children: [],
  };

  const subOrgs = await orgsData_2(organization.id);
  orgData.children = subOrgs.map(organizationData);

  data.push(orgData);

  return data;
}

const orgsData_2 = async (parent_id) => {
  
  const organizations = await findOrganizations(parent_id);

  const promises = organizations.map(organizationData);

  return await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

but it's not working....

Comment: Think about this approach reliability. You make dozens of API calls, slowing your server considerably. It would be better if you call one API endpoint and resolve yourself the desired data structure. It is better to perform complex operations on the server with one API call than do a dozen of simple calls.

Comment: You are right, but it's not our API...

Comment: Aight, will think of solution then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this solution inside of `orgsData` function.

```
const organizations = await findOrgs(parent_id);

if (!organizations.map) return; // stop the recursion when no more levels available

const promisesArray = organizations.map(organization => orgsData(organization.id))

const organizationsData = await Promise.all(promisesArray)

const data = organizations.map((organization, index) => {
    return {
        name: organization.name,
        type: "organization",
        children: organizationsData[index],
    }
})

return data
```

Comment: Getting a error: [Log] n.map is not a function. (In 'n.map(t=>p(t.id))', 'n.map' is undefined) (app-8d4ae261, line 1)

Comment: I add console.log("promisesArray", promisesArray); after const promisesArray = ... And there's my console log: 

https://ibb.co/QMtpNWm

Comment: @denken try now, I have added a condition to stop the recursion. However, I don't know how does `findOrgs` return data looks when there are no `organizations` returned. Maybe you just need to put `if (organizations.noParents === true)` or something appropriate.

Comment: =)) not good code... So anyway thank's! Your example lead to some ideas. I'll share my solution!

Comment: deaponn, you now, your solution is works fine! There's a sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/embed/immutable-hooks-602sjh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark But in my project it's not working and i getting errors.... Thank you! If I get an answer I'll paste it here.